# Why does magnetic flux decrease as turns increase in a coil but opposite is the case in magnetic circuits?

Tags: transformer, coil, magnetic-flux

In magnetic fields, we have $$N \times I = \phi \times R$$ where \$N\$ is the number of turns, \$I\$ is the current, \$\phi\$ is the flux, and \$R\$ is the magnetic reluctance.

But in coils, we have $$N \times \phi = L \times I$$ where \$L\$ is the self-inductance, so $$\phi = LI/N$$

In the first case, more \$N\$ means more \$\phi\$.

In the second case, more \$N\$ means less \$\phi\$.

Why is this the case?

Comment: How does self-inductance depend on **N**?

Comment: L is Henry, better said Self-Inductance factor.

Comment: Do you recall an \$N^2\$ factor as a proportional component to computing self-inductance **L**?

Comment: I certainly do. Oh, it factors out the N in left

Comment: Yeah, mathematic sums up. But is not there a more logical and intuitive appraoch than this?

Comment: What is logical reason to not just write Phi = L * I but we instead add N into the equation?

Comment: Yes. But I'm going to bed right now. You might look at Feynman's lectures, to start. It's good. I just wanted to kick you in the right direction tonight. No time for anything beyond that for me. Someone else may jump in.

Comment: because phi doesn't equal L*I, so we don't 'just' write it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why is this the case?*

Because you haven't considered that inductance is affected when you change the number of turns: -

$$L = \dfrac{\mu N^2 A}{d}$$

Where A is the cross sectional area of the inductor, d, is the mean path that flux travels and \$\mu\$ is the magnetic permeability constant.